# Is there any implementation of deconvolution?

Tags: python, computer-vision, convolution, deconvolution

Some one may prefer to call it the transposed convolution, as introduced [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/conv_arithmetic.html).
I'm looking forward to an implementation of the transposed convolution, in Python or C/C++.
Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.deconvolve.html

Comment: @Moberg No. It works on 1D signal. But I'm using deconvolution on images, i.e. 2D signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I am searching for an implementation of transposed convolution. I could only find one in tensorflow module. I am trying to get this working for my problem.

[Link to Tensor flow API for transposed convolution](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn/convolution#conv2d_transpose)

If it helps, you can also use the regular 2d convolution to do transposed convolution as shown in this answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/12110/24688)

Let me know if you could get this thing to work :)

Comment: OK. Finally, I managed to implement the deconvolution by hand. Just following the rule described here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/conv_arithmetic.html